# Why is there no event to update the state of the arrow drawing?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Why is there no event to update the state of the arrow drawing?

The timer is called in MainWindow.xaml.css

Code Model:

```
    public class TimeD
    {
        public double hss { get; set; }
        public double mss { get; set; }
        public double sss { get; set; }
        public void RR()
        {
            DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer
            {
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
            };
            Timer.Tick +=Timer_Tick;
            Timer.Start();
            
        }
        public void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            vmClock vmClock = new vmClock();
        }

        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        public double getHss()
        {

            hss = (time.Hour) * (360 / 12);
            return hss;
        }
        public double getMss()
        {

            mss = (time.Minute) * (360 / 60);
            return mss;
        }
        public double getSss()
        {
            sss = (time.Second) * (360 / 60);
            return sss;
        }


    }


}
```

Code ViewModel:

```
    public class vmClock : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        TimeD timeD = new TimeD();
        public double angleHour;
        public double angleMin;
        public double angleSec;

        public double AngleHour
        {
            set
            {
                angleHour = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AngleHour");

            }
            get
            {
                return angleHour;
            }
        }

        public vmClock()
        {
    
            AngleHour = timeD.getHss();
            AngleMin = timeD.getMss();
            AngleSec = timeD.getSss();


        }

        public double AngleMin
        {
            set
            {
                angleMin = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AngleMin");
             
            }
            get
            {
                return angleMin;
            }
        }

        public double AngleSec
        {
            set
            {
                angleSec = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AngleSec");

            }
            get
            {
                return angleSec;
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

    }

}
```

Code XAML:

Here is the excerpt that responds with Binding

```
                        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding AngleMin, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

                        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding AngleSec, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Could you please post your `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file?

Comment: var mw = new MainWindow
            {

                DataContext = new vmClock()
            };
            mw.Show();
            timeD.RR();

Comment: @Mr.Empty Please edit your question and replace your last code-block with the content of your MainWindow.xaml.cs file, not MainWindow.cs. The fragments you are showing are simply not enough to see the problem. One problem is evident in your `Timer_Tick` event handler: you are instantiating a new `vmClock` class and are doing nothing with it. So it will be simply get discarded by the garbage collector.